# HDMI to Ethernet and vice versa

Tags: hdmi

I am doing some project in which we need to convert HDMI IN to Ethernet and Ethernet to HDMI OUT. Please suggest any ic or any way by which I can implement this?

Answer (score 1):

A quick search using The Google for "HDMI over ethernet" resulted in many entries. [One of them](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B003LZA95W) is relatively low priced, US$15.99 and has 30 meter distance capability. I note that the device requires a pair of ethernet cables, perhaps due to the volume of data being transmitted for real-time video.

[image: HDMI over ethernet]

Note that the search returned many entries and your search may provide more suitable devices than this one item.